# mod-rewrite problem in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I'm developing a site on my localhost (Usbwebserver application). I'm using CodeIgniter framework:

url is "http://localhost/daniel/index.php"

**with the following options:**

config/routs:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

config/config:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/daniel";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

**I've tried the following .htaccess code:**

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I want to remove index.php and to load my default controller with http://localhost/daniel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /daniel/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried this and I think it worked, I mean http://localhost/daniel/site redirected me on index.php. However it shows 404 Page Not Found generated by CodeIgniter. I've added an echo at the beginning of the index.php and it echoed properly. Think there is a problem in codeigniter settings. (almost forgot to mention that I have the application folder outside of the system folder)

Comment: silly question, but you do have a controller named 'site', right?

Comment: I,ve just fixed it somehow. I don't know what was the mattter actually

Answer (score 1):

I used the hataccess from the codigniter wiki(the same that I had above):

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
# Removes the "/" at the end
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ daniel/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

With all the same option, only $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"(instead of URI_PROTOCOL) and **somehow it began to work** (and I have the aplication folder outside of the system folder)

Thank You all who kindly replied me!